# Handling Deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, transactions, deadlock

I have a procedure (`usp_LoadCDRActivated`) which calls another procedure (`usp_crs_LoadCDRsByBatch` ). The proc `usp_crs_LoadCDRsByBatch` calls six more procedures which loads data from a single staging table to other summary tables. I am running the parent proc (`usp_LoadCDRActivated`) through a queue.

Now when I start the queue, there is always deadlocks and hence the exceptions for which the queue gets disabled automatically.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Please let me know if you want to know any more details.

Below is the parent proc...

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_LoadCDRActivated]      
as      
begin      
set nocount on;      
declare @h uniqueidentifier      
        , @messageTypeName sysname      
        , @messageBody varbinary(max)      
        , @xmlBody xml      
        , @batchID int      
        , @startTime datetime      
        , @finishTime datetime      
        , @execErrorNumber int      
        , @execErrorMessage nvarchar(2048)      
        , @xactState smallint      
        , @token uniqueidentifier;      

begin transaction;      
begin try;      
    receive top(1)      
                @h = [conversation_handle]      
                , @messageTypeName = [message_type_name]      
                , @messageBody = [message_body]      
    from [LoadCDRQueue];      
    if (@h is not null)      
        begin      
            if (@messageTypeName = N'DEFAULT')      
                begin      
                    -- The DEFAULT message type is a procedure invocation.      
                    -- Extract the name of the procedure from the message body.      
                    --      
                    select @xmlBody = CAST(@messageBody as xml);      
                    select @batchID = @xmlBody.value(      
                                                        '(//batch/batchID)[1]'      
                                                        , 'int'
                                                    );      

                    save transaction usp_LoadCDR_procedure;      
                    select @startTime = GETUTCDATE();      
                    begin try      
                        exec usp_crs_LoadCDRsByBatch @batchID;      
                    end try      
                    begin catch      
                        -- This catch block tries to deal with failures of the procedure execution      
                        -- If possible it rolls back to the savepoint created earlier, allowing      
                        -- the activated procedure to continue. If the executed procedure      
                        -- raises an error with severity 16 or higher, it will doom the transaction      
                        -- and thus rollback the RECEIVE. Such case will be a poison message,      
                        -- resulting in the queue disabling.      
                        --      
                        select  @execErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),      
                                @execErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),      
                                @xactState = XACT_STATE();      
                        if (@xactState = -1)      
                            begin      
                                rollback;      
                                raiserror(N'Unrecoverable error in procedure usp_crs_LoadCDRsByBatch (%i): %i: %s', 16, 10,      
                                @batchID, @execErrorNumber, @execErrorMessage);      
                            end      
                        else if (@xactState = 1)      
                            begin      
                                rollback transaction usp_LoadCDR_procedure;      
                            end      
                    end catch      

                    select @finishTime = GETUTCDATE();      
                    select @token = [conversation_id]      
                    from sys.conversation_endpoints      
                    where [conversation_handle] = @h;      
                    if (@token is null)      
                        begin      
                            raiserror(N'Internal consistency error: conversation not found', 16, 20);      
                        end      
                    update [LoadCDRResults] set      
                    [start_time] = @starttime      
                    , [finish_time] = @finishTime      
                    , [error_number] = @execErrorNumber      
                    , [error_message] = @execErrorMessage      
                    where [token] = @token;      
                    if (0 = @@ROWCOUNT)      
                        begin      
                            raiserror(N'Internal consistency error: token not found', 16, 30);      
                        end      
                    end conversation @h;      
                end      
else if (@messageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')      
begin      
end conversation @h;      
end      
else if (@messageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error')      
begin      
declare @errorNumber int      
, @errorMessage nvarchar(4000);      
select @xmlBody = CAST(@messageBody as xml);      
with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error')      
select @errorNumber = @xmlBody.value ('(/Error/Code)[1]', 'INT'),      
@errorMessage = @xmlBody.value ('(/Error/Description)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(4000)');      
-- Update the request with the received error      
select @token = [conversation_id]      
from sys.conversation_endpoints      
where [conversation_handle] = @h;      
update [LoadCDRResults] set      
[error_number] = @errorNumber      
, [error_message] = @errorMessage      
where [token] = @token;      
end conversation @h;      
end      
else      
begin      
raiserror(N'Received unexpected message type: %s', 16, 50, @messageTypeName);      
end      
        end      
commit;      
end try      
begin catch      
    declare @error int      
            , @message nvarchar(2048);      
    select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()      
            , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()      
            , @xactState = XACT_STATE();      
    if (@xactState <> 0)      
        begin      
            rollback;      
        end;      
    raiserror(N'Error: %i, %s', 1, 60,  @error, @message) with log;      
end catch
```

end

Comment: Configure the queue so that it processes only one message at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have several instances of this procedure running concurrently. I would expect one of these instances gets the lock on the first row and all the other instances have to wait to get the lock for the first row. An alternative is to read the top n rows and use the readpast locking hint to skip the locked rows.